# How to add angular material expansion panel dynamically on button click?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting up a dynamic expansion panel in my `Angular 7` application, I am showing a `mat-expansion-panel` by default in `mat-accordion`. Now I have an **Add** button, and I want if a user clicks on this button, a new `mat-expansion-panel` should append in `mat-accordion` with a small form or 4 `form inputs`.

I tried it with `rendered2` class but it is not working for me. I might be missing something.

```
<mat-accordion id="quoteAccordion">
   <mat-expansion-panel>
       <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
             <!--  -->
               Panel Title Here
               <!--  -->
               </mat-panel-title>
                  <mat-panel-description>
                    Panel description here
                  </mat-panel-description>
       </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <!-- Panel Body -->
           <div formArrayName="services" *ngFor="let service of services.controls; let i = index">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="30" class="pr-4">
                   <mat-label> Description</mat-label>
                   <input matInput formControlName="title" required>
                   <mat-error>Description is required!</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
           </div
       <!-- /Panel Body -->
       </mat-expansion-panel>
       <!-- 
           on click of [Add] button
           Need to append another expansion
           panel with form input here
        -->
</mat-accordion>
       <!--  Ends Here -->
       </div>
<button class="w-100" matTooltip="Add" type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="addAccordion()">
       <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> ADD
</button>
```

I am expecting the output of adding dynamic `mat-expansion-panel` with `expansion-header` and the `expansion-body` contains a `form-input`.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You may use `*ngFor` directive on `<mat-expansion-panel>`and set an array property on your component ts with your panels data, then simply push values to this array to have the new panels appended.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Component.html

```
<button  type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addItem()">
       <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> ADD
</button>

<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{item.title}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{item.description}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div>details or form here</div>

  </mat-expansion-panel>

</mat-accordion>
```

Component.ts:

```
export interface myModel{
    title?:string;
    description?:string;
    ...
}


items:Array<myModel>=[{title:"default item title" , description:"default item description"}];

addItem(){
   // push object that you need to be added into array
   this.items.push({title:"new title of item"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good approach for this type of scenario.

Whenever you want to create a new set of input controls on any action (such as a click) of User, then do the followings: -

1. Create a variable of type an `Array` in `component.ts` and push an empty object into `Array` because you want to show the default control.
2. Now loop through this variable in `component.html` file using `*ngFor`.
3. Whenever user clicks on Add button, just push an empty object into the `Array` using `Array.push(object)` then angular will automatically add the new control since you have looped through the `Array`.

Let me know if it works or otherwise.